# Splash containers stops working after 30 minutes

Tags: docker, haproxy, splash-js-render

I have some issue with Aquarium and splash. They stop working after 30 minutes after the start. A number of pages for loading are 50K-80K.
I made cron job for automatically rebooting every 10 minutes, each Splash container, but it didn't work
How can I fix it?

Here is screenshot [image]
and statistic from HAProxy [image]
Here is Splash config

```
splash0:
    image: scrapinghub/splash:3.0
    command: --max-timeout 3600 --slots 150 --maxrss 1000 --verbosity 5
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    expose:
        - 8050
    mem_limit: 1000m
    memswap_limit: 1000m
    restart: always
```

And HAProxy

```
    backend splash-cluster
    option httpchk GET /
    balance leastconn

    # try another instance when connection is dropped
    retries 2
    option redispatch
    server splash-0 splash0:8050 check maxconn 150 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4
backend splash-misc
    balance roundrobin
    server splash-0 splash0:8050 check fall 15
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here is script for rebooting

```
    #!/bin/sh

echo "BEGIN" >> restart.log
for index in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6  7
do
    docker-compose restart splash$index
    echo "Restarted: Splash$index. Time: $(date '+%A %W %Y %X')" >> restart.log
    sleep 1
done
echo "END" >> restart.log
```

And it should works because I have logs in a file
Cronjob:

```
cd /var/www/project/aquarium && sh splash_restart.sh
```

Comment: Please add the output of `docker-compose stats` and `docker-compose ps` once the issue occurs

Comment: Hi, @TarunLalwani I will add this info later when splash will loading pages again

Comment: @amarynets Did you ever solve this issue? Does it happen with the latest version of Splash?

Comment: @Gallaecio No, we still reload it